# Using a ScrollView to Design a Registration Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

I'm curious. Should I use a scroll view in an activity or use a fragment to achieve the UI of the registration screen in my screenshot? Or how should I go about this for my Android Studio app? Thank you.

// XML File

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFEEF5"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#EFEEF5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22000003">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

// Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your xml?

Comment: Added my xml for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you do want the `back` button to navigate back to some other screen from the `Registration` screen? In case there are multiple fragments already that you use with your activity then you can use a `ScrollView` inside that fragment. However if this is only something like a demo app where you need to add those fields inside activity directly and show a demo of the `UI` of this `Registration` screen only to someone, then you might consider just adding a `ScrollView` in your activity and putting all the `Views` inside it.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll use a fragment instead since it’s for an actual project I’m building

Comment: if that was all you wanted to know and you can proceed further with your issue now, could you please mark it as accepted answer for your question?